# Yahoo dail is blurred out

Tags: email, yahoo-mail

I am wondering if anyone has seen this before.  Using a web browser (I have tried Chrome and IE) the email list is blurred out. I cannot read, delete or navigate when this occurs.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the colour theme by clicking on the gear icon

[image]

and selecting an alternative.

Comment: Changing the color theme did not resolve the issue.  It changes the color of the blur, but does not make anything available.